# Customizing map images in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I would like to set up my own custom map by changing the images in OpenLayers 3.

Is something like this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. when you say images, do you mean the base layer?  My understanding (I'm learning ol3 also) is that you can access several free baselayers from different places. eg OSM. and you can create your own baselayer through a webserver like geoserver.  You can download OSM data for free from geofabrik.de and style that up to serve as your baselayer

Comment: thanks for answering, and to clarify I am very much a beginner so I'm not sure what you're telling me here, so could you dumb it down a bit?If by baselayers you mean the different images for the map zooms, then yes, I do mean the baselayers. I was wondering how to access them and customize to my liking.

Answer (score 2):

Openlayers splits its layers into two types: basemap and overlays.  The basemap is the general map that you can see, like google maps, where you can zoom and pan etc.  The overlays are the data you wish to view and query.  You can only have one basemap but many overlays.

From you comments it sounds like you want to create your own styled basemap.  I would suggest using open street map (OSM) data, which can be downloaded from *geofabrik.de*.  I would also suggest you google the hell out something called geoserver which will allow you to view your styled basemap in openlayers.  Check out [the geoserver manual](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/index.html) and [boundless](http://boundlessgeo.com/) who's a company that packages a lot of open source software together, their documentation is really good.

This probably isn't what you were after but I hope it puts you in the right direction.